# select particular column in zend frmaework model

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in zend framework Below is my sql query in zend model

```
$row = $select_company_table->fetchAll($select_company_table->select()->where('manage=1 and deleteOption=0')->order('id DESC'));
```

Basically it will fetch all the columns in the table.
I want to select only 2 columns ie id and status but i don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
$select = $this->select()
               ->from(array('company_table'),array("id","status"))
                ->where('manage = ?','1') 
                ->where('deleteOption = ?','0')
                ->order('id DESC');
$row = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

**EDITED:**

```
$select = $this->select()
               ->from(array('cwi_company'),array("*"))
                ->where('manage = ?','1') 
                ->where('deleteOption = ?','0')
                ->where('passwordStatus = ?','1')
                ->where('organizationuserid IN (SELECT userId FROM cwi_passtable WHERE passwordAciveStatus =1)');
```

Comment: change the line `->from('company_table',array("id","status"))` with the `->from(array('company_table'),array("id","status"))`.

Comment: @Delta glade to help you mark it as accepted so that future users will get the benefit with it.

Comment: This is my query:
select * from cwi_company where manage=1 and deleteOption='0' and passwordStatus=1 and organizationuserid in(SELECT userId FROM cwi_passtable WHERE passwordAciveStatus ='1';

Comment: i want above query to be implement in zend model